# How to add next button to Java Selenium code

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Here is my code:

```
    private final static String tablelast   = "(//table[contains(@class,'datatable')])[last()]"; 
    private final static String next        = "(//span[text()='Next']/following::table[last()]"; 
    private static String scrape() throws Exception {
         int row_num = 1; 
         String rows = ""; 
        
         WebElement table_element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(tablelast));
         List<WebElement> rowsList = table_element.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
         List<WebElement> columnsList = null;

         while (!next.contains("disabled")) {
             driver.findElement(By.xpath(next)).click(); 
             Thread.sleep(1000);
             for (WebElement row : rowsList) {
                 columnsList = row.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
                 for (WebElement column : columnsList) {
                    rows += column.getText() + ", ";
                 }
                 rows = rows + "\n";
             }
         }
    return rows;
    }
```

This throws the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression (//span[text()='Next']/following::table[last()] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '(//span[text()='Next']/following::table[last()]' is not a valid XPath expression.
```

I am trying to test second data table of this [WEBSITE](https://www.iata.org/en/publications/directories/code-search).

1. The error seems to incorrect `NEXT` button xpath
2. The Next button code is also require attention. I am afraid its wrong

Please help me to fix these two issues

**UPDATE-1**

```
while(count ==3) {
             
                 for(WebElement trElement : tr_collection){
                 List<WebElement> td_collection = trElement.findElements(By.xpath("td"));
                 col_num++;
                   for(WebElement tdElement : td_collection){
                       rows += tdElement.getText()+"\t";
                       col_num++;                     
                    }   
                 rows = rows + "\n";
                 System.out.println("rows-->"+rows);
                 row_num++;          
                }
                
                 driver.findElement(By.xpath(next)).click(); 
                 count++;
         }
```

Comment: your xpath is invalid because that leading ( isn't closed with )

Comment: @Dmart Thanks for pointing this. I have corrected. Appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the `next` button and **disabled** `next` button which is for the last table you can identify xpath for that and then check size of the **disabled** `next` if 0 then continue and click next else break. use **infinite** loop. hope this helped.

**code**:

```
private final static String tablelast   = "(//table[contains(@class,'datatable')])[last()]"; 
private final static String next        = "(//table[contains(@class,'datatable')])[last()]/preceding::a[text()='Next'][1]"; 
private final static String disablednext        ="(//table[contains(@class,'datatable')])[last()]/preceding::span[contains(@class, 'disabled') and text()='Next'][1]";
     
private static String scrape() throws Exception {
         int row_num = 1; 
         String rows = ""; 
        
         WebElement table_element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(tablelast));
         List<WebElement> rowsList = table_element.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
         List<WebElement> columnsList = null;

         while (true) 
         {   Thread.sleep(1000);
             if (driver.findElements(By.xpath(disablednext)).size()==0)
             {
                 ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();",driver.findElement(By.xpath(next)));
                 Thread.sleep(1000);
                 for (WebElement row : rowsList) {
                   columnsList = row.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
                   for (WebElement column : columnsList) {
                      rows += column.getText() + ", ";
                 }
                 rows = rows + "\n";
             }
             }
                 else
                 {
                     break;
                 }
             }
         return rows;    
    }
```

Comment: @KundK Thanks for your favorable reply and giving me your precious time. Appreciated!! This code throwing `unknown error: Element <a class="pagination-link " href="/en/publications/directories/code-search/?airport.page=2#searchForm" data-search-nav-url-with-form="/AirportCodesSearch/Search?currentBlock=314384&amp;currentPage=12572&amp;airport.page=2">...</a> is not clickable at point (1028, 593). Other element would receive the click: <div class="gdpr-banner" data-gdpr-banner="" style="display: block;">...</div>`

Comment: @User169 : Try with js executor to click on next button. check my updated answer.

Comment: @Kuduk Thanks again for your favorable replies. Now its displaying `org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document`

Comment: perhaps the main problem is when page loads there is banner to accept cookies by clicking "Yes, Got IT" button. No?

Comment: I code to click the cookies banner and `NEXT` button is working fine but not printing any data

Comment: @User169 : where is your print statement?

Comment: I have updated my question and added my code as `UPDATE-1` Please check it

Comment: when I remove while loop + `driver.findElement(By.xpath(next)).click();` part then its displaying first page data but when I add NEXT its working but not printing

Comment: I marked your question answer + up vote but not yet fixed the loop problem. I add new problem in another question

Comment: I will check that tomorrow. It’s too late in my region.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is an 'a' tag, not span

```
//a[text()='Next']/following::table[last()]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Question (1) is answered but regarding Question(2) its now throwing the exception: `unknown error: Element <table class="datatable">...</table> is not clickable at point (681, 487). Other element would receive the click: <div class="gdpr-banner" data-gdpr-banner="" style="display: block;">...</div>`

Comment: create a new question for your new issue.

Comment: My question has two parts One is replied and second one is pending to aswer.

Comment: @DMart okay I am going to add new question for aforementioned problem that I posted as comment